# how to use meteor package in typescript file

Tags: javascript, meteor, typescript, typescript1.6

I want to use [this meteor package](https://atmospherejs.com/snamoah/useragent) in my project. I am just beginner in Typescript so having confusion about how to define declaration file. I want to be able to do like this:

```
/// <reference to platform declaration file
console.log('os: ' + platform.os.toString());
```

Any help on how to define declaration file for this package. Thanks

Comment: Show how you added the package to your project. That will give some clue.

Comment: meteor add snamoah:useragent

Comment: And you are saying that it's giving an error that `platform` is `undefined`?

Comment: my typescript compiler is giving `Cannot find name 'platform'`
Don't I need to define its declaration file first?

Answer (score 0):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22858751/1045881) on [How to import a js library without definition file in typescript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842389/how-to-import-a-js-library-without-definition-file-in-typescript-file),

Try adding

```
/// <amd-dependency path="lib/platform">
```

to the top of your file.

Comment: That means i don't need to define typescript declaration file for this module?