# How to use javascript module into typescript file

Tags: typescript, angular

Here is the .js file :

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var express=require('express');
var app=express();

var connect=mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/techo2log");
var schema=mongoose.Schema;
var userschema=new schema(
{
    name:String,
    age:Number,
    address:String,
    created_at:Date,
    updated_at:Date,

}
);

var User=mongoose.model('User',userschema);
userschema.method.dudify=function()
{
this.name=this.name+'-dude';
return this.name;
}

//making the model available to the external file
module.exports=User;
```

I want to use the User Module in my type script file.How should I write the typescript definition file for the above code so that I could import in my .ts file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import a js library without definition file in typescript file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842389/how-to-import-a-js-library-without-definition-file-in-typescript-file)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wrote a NodeJS module, so first, ensure you use `--module commonjs` as a compiler option (or inside your tsconfig.json).

Second, you just need to create a definition file. If your JS file is named 'user.js', you could name your definition file 'user.d.ts' and could look like this :

```
declare module 'user' {
    var User: any;
    export = User;
}
```

Of course, you could refine the type of `User`, but as a start, this should do the trick.

Third, you can import your module in TypeScript with such a line :

```
import User = require('user');
```

Comment: I am getting the error as "Cannot find module 'user' when importing in typescript.

Comment: I have tried all things but still getting the same error.Also tried adding the    /// <reference path="../../../server/user.d.ts" but no success.I have kept both user.js and user.d.ts in the same folder called server.And I want to use the module in other ts file repos.ts  which is in folder repos.