# How can I import an external library without creating a custom .d.ts file OR turning noimplicitany off for my entire project?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Simple question - every time I import a new npm library that doesn't have a .d.ts file, I am creating a stub .d.ts file with lots of lines like this, just to compile:

```
function SomeFunctionINeed(...args: any[]): any
```

We love TS but this is our biggest hang-up right now.  How can I import libraries and allow implicit `any`, without allowing implicit `any` for my entire project?

Comment: Which version of TypeScript are you using? In 2.1 or 2.2 it will automatically type to `any` when you have installed the npm library.

Comment: @unional yes - how can I get that to work without disabling noimplicitany for my whole project?  I want to allow "any" types just for those libraries and not lose the power of noimplicitany for the rest of our code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import a js library without definition file in typescript file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842389/how-to-import-a-js-library-without-definition-file-in-typescript-file)

Comment: Same question, though @unional posted the best answer here a month before it was posted in that thread though.

Answer (score 2):

To keep the benefit of `noImplicityAny` while avoiding this, you can do:

```
declare module '*';
```

Create this file and add it to your tsconfig.json. e.g.:

```
// custom-typings/any-modules.d.ts
declare module '*';

// tsconfig.json
{
  "include": [
    "custom-typings"
  ]
}
```

Original discussion: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13348

Comment: Wow - `declare module '*';` works!  Have looked for this solution for a while, thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that we're now using `declare module 'someModule';` instead of *.  With *, *all* modules are assumed to have no types which causes some problems (like never checking if types are available on this lib) - we like to specify on a per-module basis which types we don't intend to add.