# Using commonjs modules in Angular4 services?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typescript2.2

I first tested using the commonjs module that I installed like this:

```
npm install the-module;
```

I then created `main.js` which looked something like this:

```
var module = require('the-module');
module.doStuff();
```

Then compiled `main.js` with webpack into `bundle.js`, loaded it in the browser, and it did stuff.

Now I want to use `the-module` inside an angular 4 service.  How should I import it?

I also found [this article](http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-create-an-angular-2-library-and-how-to-consume-it-jspm-vs-webpack/) on how to create an angular 2 component library.  Curious whether this set of steps is required for all commonjs modules that will be imported by Angular or whether there is a more direct approach?

## Related Concepts

Ended up writing this article:

[using-vanilla-npm-javascript-modules-with-typescript](https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/using-vanilla-npm-javascript-modules-with-typescript-5052ca503178)

Comment: Naturally you can `import` any module ( any compatible at least ) and probably all you need is a "typescript shape" of the module exports for usage. [How to import a js library without definition file in typescript file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842389/how-to-import-a-js-library-without-definition-file-in-typescript-file) is one of many sources of answers on this. Alternately since it is **your** library, then why not go all the way and and bundle it properly from the beginning. There was a recent talk at NgConf on this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=unICbsPGFIA

Comment: Well in this case i'm importing https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv, but I'm sure I can fork it and add the necessary tweaks.  Thanks for the links.  Doing a deep dive now.