# How to import js file in typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I want to import js file in typescript.
And I want to access object and function in the js files.
Also I added js file in index.html but It doesn't working too.
so I find a clue that "import '[js file path]'" but it doesn't working.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import '../../pages/mobile.js';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-success',
  templateUrl: 'success.html'
})

export class SuccessPage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParms: NavParams) {

let centerPos =  new atlan.maps.UTMK(953933.75, 1952050.75);

 }
}
```

This is success.ts file. I want to find 'atlan' object. 
Give me a solution please. Thx a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import a js library without definition file in typescript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842389/how-to-import-a-js-library-without-definition-file-in-typescript-file)

Comment: Extremely valid question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use the [declare](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2013/07/22/quick-tip-typescript-declare-keyword/) keyword so you do not get any compilation errors. You can do the following

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
     ....
    /* Here you are telling typescript compiler to 
       ignore this variable it did not originate with typescript.*/
    declare var atlan: any; 

    @Component({
      selector: 'page-success',
      templateUrl: 'success.html'
    })

export class SuccessPage {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your file `../../pages/mobile.js`, you must `export` your atlan object (*if you can edit this file of course*), then, you import it the same way you do with everything.