# Including JS package import in a TypeScript project

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-module-resolution

I'm working on a TypeScript/Angular project, and I've found a package I'd like to use with it called SongPro that will help me parse some files. Here is that project on [GitHub](https://github.com/SongProOrg/songpro-javascript) and [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/songpro?activeTab=code).

This project has no Type definitions and I'm not really sure how to include it in my project.  I've [read about](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27915156/79677) how to get around this my creating some fake/temp typedefs like this:

File: `songpro.d.ts`

```ts
declare module "*";
```

And then somewhere in my project:

```ts
import * as songpro from 'songpro'

console.log(songpro);
```

That log produces only an empty object `{}`. I would have expected either a populated object or maybe even `undefined`, but an empty object is strange. I'm at a loss for what's going on.  How can I use this package in my project?

---

### Edit

Editing based on what I've tried with the answer from **Arjis Chakraborty** below.

I have created the file `./typings/songpro.d.ts` with this content:

```ts
declare module 'songpro' {
  export interface ISongDetails {
    title: string;
    artist: string;
    sections: ISongDetails[];
  }
  export function parse(contents: string | Buffer): ISongDetails;
}
```

Now when I have the following in my project:

```ts
import * as songpro from 'songpro'

console.log(songpro);
```

the imported `songpro` object seems to recognise the typedefs that are declared

[image]

However when I build the project I get this error:

```
- error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'songpro'. 'C:/Users/FiniteLooper/Projects/LyricConverter/node_modules/songpro/dist/songpro.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/songpro` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'songpro';`

1 import * as songpro from 'songpro'
                           ~~~~~~~~~
```

That message tells me to declare a module in a `.d.ts` file which I have already done and it can see! What is going on?

*(And no, sadly there is no `@types/songpro` project)*

However, if I do this:

```ts
const songpro = require('songpro');

console.log(songpro);
```

then I am back to getting an empty object logged out to the console with no build errors.

[image]

But if I use a capitalized `SongPro` instead of lower case

```ts
const songpro = require('SongPro');

console.log(songpro);
```

Then I get an empty object logged out in a different way

[image: SongPro]

I am very unclear on what is going wrong here.

Comment: I tried `npm install` that package, then the import led to `node_modules/songpro/dist/songpro.js`. But when I checked the contents, it doesn't do anything with `module.exports`. So it remains with its default value, i.e. an empty object `{}`. And that file also shows a top-level variable `var songpro;` which will be global if you load it with a `<script>` tag in a browser, but will not be accessible if you load it from a CommonJS module.

Comment: Ok, good to know, thanks for the info!  It's looking like this package is just build wrong.  I think I will just have to manually copy it's contents into my project to be able to use its functions.

Comment: I've created an issue on that project now too: https://github.com/SongProOrg/songpro-javascript/issues/34

Comment: So my solution was to re-write the project in typescript, send the owner a PR, and they merged it in.  Not the quickest solution but it worked and the owner was super nice and understanding about it!

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```js
declare module songpro {
    interface ISongDetails {
        title: string;
        artist: string;
        sections: ISongDetails[];
    }
    function parse(contents: string | Buffer) : ISongDetails;
}
```

Comment: I've put that in a `songpro.d.ts` file and when I try to import it as in my original question I get this compile error: "TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'songpro'. 'node_modules/songpro/dist/songpro.js' implicitly has an 'any' type".

Does the `*.d.ts` file need to be in a special location?

Comment: I've editied my question with a few more details about what I have tried since adding this.  FYI, I've since learned that the module name needs to be in quotes here and the interface and function need to be marked with `export`